# how to say what happens when you press a button in ahk?

Tags: autohotkey

how do I make an specific function happen if an specific button is pressed?

for example, there is an variable named "ef". So now, if I press ctrl+alt+;, an message box will pop up, with the buttons abort, retry and ignore. so, if I press abort, the variable "ef"‘s value will become efabort. If I press retry, it‘s value will become efretry. otherwise, if I press Ignore, ef‘s value will become efignore.
Is that possible? if yes, please leave an answer containing the code.

start with this:

```
ef = 000

<!<^;::
MsgBox,2,set ef,what do you want to set ef to?
```

Any answers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [variable](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Intro) is a placeholder for a value. The value can change, nevertheless a variable can only hold one value at a time.

To store a value in a variable is recommended to use the expression method that uses the colon-equal operator (:=).

```
ef := "" ; initialize the variable in the auto-execute section (top of the script) 

MsgBox,2,set ef,what do you want to set ef to?

IfMsgBox Abort
    ef := "efabort"
IfMsgBox Retry
    ef := "efretry"
IfMsgBox Ignore
    ef := "efignore"

; To return a given value of a variable within commands, you need to enclose the variable in percent signs

MsgBox % "The value in the variable ef is now " . ef . "."
```